# Flatten Nested XML/hierarchy using XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, soa

I have a nested hierarchial xml structure which is to be flattened using xsl transformation. Following is the scenario.

```
<company>
  <Managers>
    <Manager>
       <Name>Matt</Name>
       <ID>1</ID>
       <Manager>
          <Name>Joe</Name>
          <ID>11</ID>
          <Manager>
          <Name>Dave</Name>
          <ID>111</ID>
       </Manager>
       </Manager>
    </Manager>
    <Manager>
        <Name>mike</Name>
          <ID>2</ID>>
    </Manager>
  </Managers>
</company>
```

result:

```
Matt 1
Joe 11
Dave 111
Mike 2
```

Comment: So have you tried _anything_? Read any tutorials? What is your difficulty, exactly?

Comment: Hmm.  Yeah.  I kinda assumed the question was what's the proper XPath.  The XSLT is pretty trivial.  In the future, it's best to post a sample of what you've attempted

Comment: Please don't do tag spamming and restrict to tags directly related.

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative via @Mathias Mueller,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="Manager">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ID" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Why this is better: It will more properly control the text output (assuming you really do want to output this to plaintext format).  It also is more XSLT template oriented, which tends to be more extensible and maintainable than having `for-each` loops hanging around.

Using the `descendant-or-self` axis:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="//Managers">
       <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::Manager">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />: <xsl:value-of select="ID" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:transform>
```

Output:

```
  Matt: 1 Joe: 11 Dave: 111 mike: 2
```

http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQB

Comment: If you output a space character within `xsl:text`, then why not put `: ` inside `xsl:text`, too? Also, I don't think there is a need to match `Managers`, http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQB/2.

Comment: I did the space character because otherwise it gets absorbed - but the : doesn't.  Your method is better though, I didn't think to use apply-templates within the template.